# How do you split the text

Tags: text, effects

You see I want to know how this split inbetween the text is achieved like how it slants. Also does anyone know what the font to this is? It's really cool, or does anyone have any fonts that are similar to this? Thanks guys![image: ASAP ROCKY]

Comment: Software? What have you tried?

Comment: @Scott Photoshop CS6 and I have tried literally everything! Including cutting it in half and moving it to make it like that

Comment: Why did "cutting it in half and moving it to make it like that" not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a rectengular selection covering the top half of the text. Then from the menu I chose:

Select > Transform Selection

and rotated the selection about 5°. Then I cut & paste this selection and moved the layer down left. Finally I added a 2px drop shadow.

I used Arial Black as font but that's not the one from your graphic.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How do you cut it because I've done the transformation but I cant seem to cut it?

Comment: I merged the text layer with an new empty layer and then did ctrl+x and ctrl+v.